DMI from different timeframe repainting
I have an indicator that uses the graphic time frame and a higher time frame to set an alert using only DMI. But Im having some king of repainting. Because historical bars signals are different from the signal with live bars.
I was using this to get the dmi
[dmip15x,dmim15x,adx15x] = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),ta.dmi(14,14),lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
I tried to solve this by using this instead, but its given me not "repainting" but delay
high15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),high[1],lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
low15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),low[1],lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
close15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),close[1],lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
tr15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),ta.tr[1],lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
trur15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),ta.rma(ta.tr[1], len),lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
//tr15 = math.max(high15 - low15, math.abs(high15 - close15), math.abs(low15 - close15))
up15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),ta.change(high[1]),lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
down15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),-ta.change(low[1]),lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
plusDM15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),na(up15) ? na : (up15 > down15 and up15 > 0 ? up15 : 0),lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
minusDM15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),na(down15) ? na : (down15 > up15 and down15 > 0 ? down15 : 0),lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
//trur15 = ta.rma(tr15[i], len)
dmip15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),fixnan(100 * ta.rma(plusDM15, len) / trur15),lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
dmim15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),fixnan(100 * ta.rma(minusDM15, len) / trur15),lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
sum15 = dmip15 + dmim15
adx15 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid,str.tostring(timeFrame),100 * ta.rma(math.abs(dmip15 - dmim15) / (sum15 == 0 ? 1 : sum15), lensig),lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)
Anyone who had solved this in a different way without delay or repainting?
